# Trying to close a popup window

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsm

I'm making a script that should automatically activate some xlsm macros that copy data from a csv file.  The script works fine, however during the copying I may get a popup such as

> Your defect number is large.  Import and data consolidation can take dozens of minutes.  Please wait patiently!

After this popup appears, the process can only be continued after the popup has been closed.  I'd like to close, or ignore, this automatically within my script.

Right now I've resolved it using an AutoHotkey script that recognizes a popup windows and presses the `ok` button in it.  I'm calling that script using some pretty simple Python.  Is there an easier way?

```
import win32api
import win32con

win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_*blinded_key*,0,0,0)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_*blinded_key*, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Comment: Are you asking for a better way to handle this issue? Or what?

Comment: I found solution by myself and then just edited post with this solution. But if there are other less complicated ways to resolve- I'll be appreciate